# Python reverse() for palindromes

Tags: python, reverse, palindrome

I'm just getting started in python, and I'm trying to test a user-entered string as a palindrome. My code is:

```
x=input('Please insert a word')
y=reversed(x)
if x==y:
    print('Is a palindrome')
else:
    print('Is not a palindrome')
```

This always returns false because y becomes something like `<reversed object at 0x00E16EF0>` instead of the reversed string.
What am I being ignorant about? How would you go about coding this problem?

Comment: Just because a function is named like something you need, that doesn't mean you can use it without seeing it's definition first. Take a look at [this page](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reversed). `reversed` returns an *iterator*, and I'm pretty sure that's not what you wanted.

Comment: how about if I used:
`y=[x].reverse` ?

Comment: That's really not what you want either for multiple reasons: `[x]` creates a single element list where the first element is `x`. Then when you reverse the list, you now get a list back instead of an iterator, so `y` is still not a string.

Comment: @user470379 okay... :/ Perhaps this isn't the best way, but I just want to get a feel for the lang... how would I do it by treating `x` as a list of chars (ok, so single character strings), and reversing that list?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try `y = x[::-1]`.  This uses splicing to get the reverse of the string.

`reversed(x)` returns an iterator for looping over the characters in the string in reverse order, *not* a string you can directly compare to `x`.

Comment: This is not such a good idea in the case of a large strings and lists.

Answer (score 8):

`reversed` returns an iterator, which you can make into a string using the `join` method:

```
y = ''.join(reversed(x))
```

Comment: Better yet, `str(reversed(x))`

Comment: @kindall '<reversed object at 0x0000000002C53E80>'

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhrgh, sorry, brain fart. I assumed the `str()` constructor would take any iterable and concatenate it into a string. This is of course totally wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, a lambda from the answers above for quick palindrome check:

```
isPali = lambda num: str(num) == str(num)[::-1]
```

example use:

```
isPali(9009) #returns True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
def pal(name):
        sto_1 = []
        for i in name:
                sto_1.append(i)

        sto_2 = []
        for i in sto_1[::-1]:
                sto_2.append(i)

        for i in range(len(name)):
                if sto_1[i] == sto_2[i]:
                        return "".join(sto_1), "".join(sto_2)
                else:
                        return "no luck"

name = raw_input("Enter the word :")
print pal(name)
```

Comment: or just:
````def pal(name):
           return name==name[::-1]````

Answer (score 0):

```
list(reverse( mystring )) == list( mystring )
```

or in the case of numbers

```
list(reverse( str(mystring) )) == list( str(mystring) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
def palindrome(string):
    i = 0 
    while i < len(string):
        if string[i] != string[(len(string) - 1) - i]:
            return False
        i += 1
    return True
```

print palindrome("hannah")

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to find whether original & reverse are same or not:-

```
if a == a[::-1]:
```

#this will reverse the given string, eventually will give you idea if the given string is palindrome or not.

Comment: Just curious, how is this a different than the accepted answer?